# D3 Clock not appearing on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, d3.js

Can't seem to figure this out for an hour now. I have a D3 clock which appears fine locally on my Rails project, however, doesn't on production.

I have done the following:

`bundle install`

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Looks like I had CKEDITOR JS errors which for some reason wasn't running other JS files on production.